# How to tell my research advisor I'd like to drop a class?

Tags: phd, graduate-school

I'm currently in my first semester pursuing a PhD in Computer Science.

Comment: Since you are a PhD student, you should prioritize your research over classes.  Why do you think you need to tell your advisor?  Is his permission required?

Comment: His permission is not required, but he knows I'm in the course and has high expectations for me. @Anonymous Physicist

Comment: OP is pulling all-nighters at the start of the program already. Assuming this goes on cost of their total sleep time: This must stop; it's not viable, period. However, if it is just on cost of your general research time, it may be a good toolbox for their later research, so trading the course time with research time might be a consideration. So, ask yourself where the priority is for this phase.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I disagree (in part) with this.  Courses are meant to be a component of the degree, and the thesis and associated research is only completed in *partial fulfillment* of the requirements of the degree.  It’s difficult to say from afar, but I find it refreshing to see that in this case it seems the OP has taken a course where there is substantial contents.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The relation between coursework and PhDs is country dependent. (But if a country pads out undergraduate degree courses with irrelevant Gen-Ed "electives" it's not surprising that students *need* to take more courses at graduate level...)

Comment: Along the same lines as Captain Emacs comment: what you're learning now may not seem relevant to your research but in two years, you might find you need exactly some of the ideas you're learning in this class. This doesn't mean you'll recall the tools exactly, but it *will* give you the knowledge of places to go to answer your question(s) relating to whatever topic is at hand.

Comment: I understand this course may be relevant later on, but the amount of hours I'm spending on this is conflicting with my research efforts. I am more curious on how to approach my advisor which such an issue since I am leaning towards dropping it. I can always take another course that fufills this requirement. No one looks at the courses you took during your PhD, they look at your research, atleast this is what I've been told. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @alephzero I still think not everything can be taught at the undergraduate level (irrespective of electives) and that meaningful graduate courses are part of what makes a meaningful advanced degree.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero So despite the amount of time I'm spending on this course and how much it's conflicting with research, you recommend staying in the course? I don't even have time to apply for fellowships. And my advisor is currently seeking NASA funding for my research so I need to be on top of it... I came to stack exchange to look for approaches on how to bring this up considering the detailed information I've given. I appreciate the first answer, but hoping to get an alternative perspective/answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Bwoods you're starting your PhD so yes I would expect you devote lots of time to your courses at the expense of your research (this might be discipline dependent but in physics people do, in their first year, spent a lot of time on courses).  Now, this may not be the best course *for you* to do this, but you should expect to have to do this in whatever course will replace this one if you drop it.  Only you can measure what you get out of that course, but "takes too much time from my research" could be a weaker excuse for a candidate starting a degree (up to discipline specific culture).

Comment: @Bwoods The research component is (at least historically) only *one* component of the graduate degree; the other components certainly include courses.  (Here's a meme on a situation graduate students in physics will recognize: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mm-4PltMB2A&app=desktop)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I see where you're coming from and I noticed this is a big difference between classic sciences like Physics vs. a relatively new field like CS... At my institution, it's definitely researched focus with course requirements, but we don't take a ton of courses. For example we only have to take 3 courses by the end of our first year. I've noticed a similar trend with other CS departments. Research is definitely priority #1, but yes there are the minimal course requirements

Answer (score 7):

> Dear Supervisor,
>
> I am taking the AI course.  I need X hours/week to do well in this
>   course.  My other courses only take Y hours/week.  I am considering
>   dropping this elective course so that I can devote X more hours/week
>   to my research.  Do you think this is a good idea?
>
> Thanks for your advice,
>
> Student

Note:  Most likely your advisor will support you if you want to spend time on research.  But they may know something you did not tell us on Stack Exchange.  If your advisor says no, you can still tell them you have decided to drop the course.

Comment: -1 Don't ask an open question if you have already decided. If you ask the question, make sure you are ready to follow the advice.

Comment: This is the sort of issue that should be discussed in person, not by mail. Go visit them. Talk it out.